# How to make a footer without the header on the very first page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I just nead to write a little report. So I need not a titlepage but I just start out with a title, names, an abstract and starts to write. But I want the footer on the very firts page without a header. Both header and fooder should be on the following pages. How to make that working?

Here my minimal example. Kind regards! And thank you very much in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside, twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%Header/footer
\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\underline{Name Name}}{}{\underline{\today}}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\underline{Name Name}}{}{\underline{\today}}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}}  
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
   \begin{center}
{\fontsize{40}{48} \bfseries \textsc{Hirshfeld surfaces}}\linebreak

\vspace{5pt}

Name\\
Name

\vspace{5pt}

\end{center}



\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}


\leavevmode
\vspace{20pt}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{something something}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using custom headers and footers (`mystyle`), you could just define a similar footer-only style called `mytitlestyle` and tell the first page to use that style with the command `\thispagestyle{mytitlestyle}`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside, twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Header/footer
\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\underline{Name Name}}{}{\underline{\today}}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\underline{Name Name}}{}{\underline{\today}}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}}  

\makepagestyle{mytitlestyle}
\makeevenfoot{mytitlestyle}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}
\makeoddfoot{mytitlestyle}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{mytitlestyle}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
   \begin{center}
{\fontsize{40}{48} \bfseries \textsc{Hirshfeld surfaces}}\linebreak
\vspace{5pt}

Name\\
Name

\vspace{5pt}
\end{center}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\leavevmode
\vspace{20pt}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\section{something something}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Note: You can obtain the default page numbering with `\thispagestyle{plain}`.